# Disabling and enabling onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p id = "a" onclick = "doStuff()">Textextextext</p>
<p onclick = "disable()">disable the first p</p>
<p onclick = "enable()">enable the first p</p>
function disable() {
    document.getElementById("a").onclick = null;
}
function enable() {
    document.getElementById("a").onclick = //command?//
}
```

I don't want this to BE a button, I just want to make a clickable paragraph that can become unclickable. What's the command to enable the onclick? I've already searched this question but can't find an answer, so I'm asking.

Comment: What's an unclickable paragraph? Your paragraph contains text, so what you are attempting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to have a variable to store whether it is *clickable* or not. Please check snippet.

```js
var canDoStuff = true;

function disable() {
   canDoStuff = false;
}
function enable() {
   canDoStuff = true;
}

function doStuff(){
  if ( !canDoStuff ) return; /* Do nothing if canDoStuff == false */
  alert( "Doing STuff" );
}
```

```html
<p id = "a" onclick = "doStuff()">Textextextext</p>
<p onclick = "disable()">disable the first p</p>
<p onclick = "enable()">enable the first p</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable, you can use

```
document.getElementById(id).style.pointerEvents="none";
document.getElementById(id).style.cursor="default";
```

To enable

```
document.getElementById(id).style.pointerEvents="auto";
    document.getElementById(id).style.cursor="pointer";
```